# What points in $[0,1)$ will have two binary expansions?

Tags: binary, decimal-expansion

What points in $[0,1)$ will have two binary expansions?

I know that $\frac{1}{2}$ has the two expansions $0.1\bar{0}$ and $0.0\bar{1}$

$0.1\bar{0}$ is found by starting with $\frac{1}{2}$ and finding the binary expansion

$0.0\bar{1}$ is found by working backwards from the expansion to find the fraction.

But how do I go about finding other fractions that have two decimal expansions?

Comment: In a given base $b$, the numbers with multiple expansions are those that end in infinitely many zeros, which means they are an integer multiple of $b^{-n}$ for some number $n$.

Comment: That's two binary expansion, not decimal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Partial answer: Any nonzero rational in $[0,1)$ with a terminating representation has two binary expansions.

Suppose $x\in (0,1)$ is rational, $x\ne 0$, and
$$
x = 0.d_1 \dotsm d_n
$$
for binary digits $d_i$. As $x\ne 0$, we have $d_n = 1$:
$$
x = 0.d_1 \dotsm d_{n-1} 1
$$
But now it's easy to see and show that 
$$
x = 0.d_1 \dotsm d_{n-1} 0 \overline{1}
$$
is another representation of $x$.

Comment: Assuming the rational representation terminates, i.e. it is not a recurrent decimal. Isn't it?

Comment: @taninamdar Yes, true. I qualified my (partial) answer even more.

Comment: These numbers are called [dyadic rationals](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dyadic_rational).

Answer (score 1):

As BrianO explains in his answer, any rational number that can be written with a *terminating* binary expansion has two distinct binary representations:  one in which the binary representation terminates in a $1$, and one in which the binary representation terminates in $0\overline{1}$.

So the question in the OP reduces to: which rational numbers in $[0,1)$ can be written as a terminating binary expansion?

The answer is:  Any rational number which, when written in lowest terms, has a denominator that is a pure power of $2$.

Comment: These numbers are called [dyadic rationals](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dyadic_rational).